# GridView LinkButton Click Event Is Not Getting Fire When Using Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview on a webform.
In that gridview using TemplateField i have created a link button.
I have created a linkbutton_click event.But it does not get fired when i attach masterpage to this particular webform.
If i remove masterpage and run the code then the linkbutton_click event get fired.

I want to get linkbutton_click event to be get fired when using masterpage.
So please help me to get out of this problem.
Thans in advance.

Comment: show us some code, and are using item command for button click or some thing else??

Comment: protected void lnkDeptName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lbtn = new LinkButton();
        lbtn = (LinkButton)sender;

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lbtn.NamingContainer;
        int Index = row.RowIndex;

        LinkButton lnkDeptName = (LinkButton)grdDepartment.Rows[Index].FindControl("lnkDeptName");
                txtDeptName.Text = Convert.ToString(lnkDeptName.Text.Trim());

                ViewState["DeptId"] = Convert.ToString(grdDepartment.DataKeys[Index]["Id"]);
            }

Comment: I am using above code to create LinkButton in LinkButton_Click Event.

Comment: edit the question instead this code is not telling any details

Comment: When i clicked on the linkbutton then on postback the gridview also vanishes from the page.

Comment: you dont need to use that, give an item command to that link button, move the code to the grid item command event, when command name is equal to given item command

Comment: This happens for any controls on any page.On Postback all the controls gets vanish from the page & the event handler for that control is also not working.